# A multi-table JOIN query as subquery to a query that JOINS the same tables. Good or bad?

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, subquery, query-performance

I have the following tables in my postgres database

```
- power_relations        - (id, properties)
- power_relation_members - (id, power_relation_id, member_id, member_type)
- power_lines            - (id, geom)
- power_nodes            - (id, geom)
```

A `power_relation` can have multiple members which can either be `power_nodes` or `power_lines`. I use `power_relation_members` to track this polymorphic many-to-many relation.

The query I need to write has to return all the `power_lines` that belong to `power_relations` that contains `power_lines` matching a condition.

For example, if I have a

```
powerlines:

id, geom
----------
1, abc
2, d
3, g
4, j
5, m
6, abc

power_relation_members:

member_id, power_relation_id
----------------------------
1, r_1
2, r_1
3, r_1
4, r_2
5, r_2  

power_relations:

id, properties
--------------
r_1, "relation1"
r_2, "relation2"
```

In the above data, line 1 and 6 have the geom = 'abc'. Lines 1 - 3 are related to relation 1, lines 4-5 to relation 2 and no relation for line 6.
I would want to get all the `power_lines` that are related (via `power_relation` to the `power_line` whose geom is `abc`. That means, I need lines 1, 2, 3 as results from my query.

I could achieve my result in two steps:

1. Get the distinct id's of `power_relations` that have `power_lines` that match my condition
2. Get all the `power_lines` that are related to the `power_relations` whose id is in the ids fetched from step 1.

Instead, I wanted to do this all in one query by doing the step 1 in a subquery. This includes joining the same tables in the subquery and its outer query. This is how my query looks and it gives me the results as I expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.id FROM powerline l
JOIN power_relation_members m
ON (l.id = m.member_id AND m.member_type = 'way')
JOIN power_relations r
ON (m.power_relation_id = r.id
    AND r.id in (
        SELECT DISTINCT s_r.id FROM powerline s_l
        JOIN power_relation_members s_m
        ON (s_l.id = s_m.member_id AND s_m.member_type = 'way')
        JOIN power_relations s_r
        on (s_m.power_relation_id = s_r.id)
        WHERE s_l.geom = 'somestring'
    )
);
```

You may see the simulation in the fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2493b

I'm not very familiar with how the database's perform and I would like to know if this single query is optimal compared to the two step individual queries or if there is a better and optimal way to achieve the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you need to join all three tables every time. For your specific example, what about the following query:

```
WITH rel AS (
  SELECT prm.power_relation_id
  FROM power_relation_members prm
  JOIN power_lines pl ON prm.member_id = pl.id
  WHERE pl.geom = :BIND_VAR_HERE -- in this case, 'abc'
  GROUP BY prm.power_relation_id
) SELECT
  pl.id, pl.geom
FROM power_relation_members prm
JOIN rel r ON prm.power_relation_id = r.power_relation_id
JOIN power_lines pl on prm.member_id = pl.id;
```

You reference `member_type` and `power_relation_members.id` in your SQL, but nowhere are they mentioned in your post apart from the DDL.. Is this important logically, or just a filter?

Comment: This query works very well. I have even tried something similar before trying the one I posted in the question. My question is to know which one do you suggest on using? With regards to efficiency and performance. 

btw, `member_type` is just for filtering and `power_relation_members.id` isn't important.

Comment: I suggest using the one that has the shortest execution time.  heh.  :)  I would say that your design is PROBABLY not ideal to begin with, but I don't know if that's something that could be altered.  (if it is, you might consider a second question with regard to your design)